# How Do I Deal With Django Session Data for Storing Users ID?

Tags: django, session

This may sound too easy to understand but I am not sure I am having my head around it.

When a user is signing up in the first page of my app, I have `request.session['user_id']` set which is used in page two of the sign up to complete registration. The `user_id` is the primary key to user in **USER TABLE** but I don't want to store user_id in `session`. I fear it might be tampered with and the **WRONG** row might get updated.

I would want something like a *token* that would be generated by my script but **Django's SESSION TABLE** only has three columns (*session_key, session_data, expire_date*) and it saves session details to it automatically.

My questions precisely are:

1. Can I tinker with the **SESSION TABLE** and add a `session_token` to it or I have to create my own table?
2. How do I get the `session_token` to automatically save like other columns in Django **SESSION TABLE**?
3. Or is `request.session['user_id'] okay and safe?
4. Do all these also apply to **COOKIES** and why do I need to use cookies when `SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE` is set to `FALSE`?

Comment: Django community is very sensible about security. IMHO the way sessions are managed is absolutely safe. (I worked in a banking application based on Django)

Comment: @Griffosx: Are you are saying `request.session['user_id'] is okay and safe?

Comment: @Yax why don't you use form wizard for multiple page sign up process

Comment: @rajasimon: I am using `modelForm` except if I don't understand you. I don't know how to use it across multiple pages. Though the form in my second page is `forms.Form`. Any link to read about what you are saying?

Comment: @Yax They tell clearly in the beginning `“form wizard” application that splits forms across multiple Web pages. It maintains state in one of the backends so that the full server-side processing can be delayed until the submission of the final form` Here is the link https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The session is stored in the database, not in the user's cookie. There is no way for the user to change that data. The only thing stored in the cookie is the hash of the session ID itself.

Comment: Okay but how do I regenerate the hash of the session ID and update session table each time a user logs in to avoid fixation assuming I am using cookies?

Comment: What? That has nothing to do with your question: you were talking about signing up, not logging in. Nevertheless, that is of course exactly what Django does: as a proper security-conscious web framework, this is all taken care of for you. See [the implementation of the login method](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py#L98).

Comment: This answers 1 to 3? How about 4?

Comment: I don't understand 4, I'm afraid. Why do you say "Why do I need to use cookies"? What makes you think you need to?

Comment: I mean when you set `SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE` to `FALSE`, does it make the session a cookie. I don't seem to get it. Sessions expire when browser closes. I don't understand what setting it false is supposed to mean.

Comment: No, sessions don't normally expire when the browser closes: this is (for example) how the "remember me" checkbox on a login form works. Usually they expire after a few weeks. But as I mentioned above, the *session ID* is already a cookie, and this setting does nothing to change that; all it does is change when that cookie expires.